# Union Function call in OCaml

Tags: function, module, ocaml, union

```
module type SET =
sig
  type 'a set
  val emptyset : 'a set
  val union : 'a set -> 'a set -> 'a set    
end

module Set : SET =
struct
  type 'a set = 'a -> bool

  let emptyset : 'a set = fun _ -> false

  let union (s1 : 'a set) (s2 : 'a set) : 'a set =
    fun x -> s1 x || s2 x
end
```

How can i call the union function in this, can anybody show me an example? as i am just in the learning process of OCaml language, and not able to understand the function calls inside a module.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your design. The type  `Set.set` is *abstract* because it's constrained by the `SET` signature. You can union two empty sets, but you can never create any other set.

The actual function call is very straightforward. You just need to specify that you're accessing values from the `Set` module.

```
Set union Set.emptyset Set.emptyset
```

Or:

```
Set.(union emptyset emptyset)
```